# iOS crashes when launched by custom URL - How to debug including Console?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, debugging, url-scheme

I have added a custom URL scheme to my iOS App. So a link `myapp://do/something` will be handled by my app. This works fine as long as the app is running in the background. So switching from the app to Safari, calling the URL, confirming to open the link in my app and automatically switching back to my app works fine.

Problem is, that the app crashes, when the URL is used while the is completely closed.

I assume that there is some problem with how the URL is handled. A [`MZFormSheetController`](https://github.com/m1entus/MZFormSheetController) should be displayed:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    // Run some tests and check if URL should be handled
    ...

    // Show ViewController to handle URL
   SomeViewController *someVC = [[SomeViewController alloc] init];
   MZFormSheetController *formSheet = [MZFormSheetController mcDefaultWithViewController:someVC];   

   // Does NOT crash, if the following line is disabled
   [formSheet presentAnimated:true completionHandler:nil];
}
```

It is obvious, that there is some problem with the presentation of the `MZFormSheetController` However I cannot verify that, because **I cannot debug this situation properly**.

There are several other questions on how to debug the app launch by a custom URL and the answer is always the same:

- Use the Xcode *Edit Scheme* option to change the launch settings
- Change from *"Automatically"* to *"Wait for executable to be launched"*
- Run the app on device or simulator. App will not start automatically
- Call the custom URL (e.g. in Safari) to launch the app
- Xcode attaches the debugger to the app process

This works fine, the debugger is attached automatically, I can use breakpoints, etc. However the **Console** does not work. Thus I do not get any information on what exactly is going on.

When the app crashed Xcode jumps to `UIApplicationMainUIApplicationMain` within the `main.m`. It shows a simple `SIGABRT` hint but no detailed information what so ever.

**How do I manage to get any details information about the source of the crash?**

Comment: The Xcode lldb console doesn't work, but you can use Device Manager to view the device's logs directly.

Comment: How exactly do I do that? I assume you mean the Xcode menu `Window\Devices`? There I can select my iPhone (the one I use to test the app) and click on `Show device logs`. However the log is empty.

When selecting a simulator instead of my real iPhone, there is no such option at all. So, how do I get the debug information?

Comment: In the right-hand panel, on the bottom left, there's a button with an arrow pointing up.  Click on that to reveal the console log.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to see the logs. However they do not contain any useful information related to my problem. There thousands of messages related to my app, e.g. loading different resources, etc. But no information about the crash.